# Codename one missing from NetBeans plugins on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, codenameone

I am on Ubuntu 16.04  with NetBeans 8.1 - fresh install provided by Ubuntu SW center + OpenJDK - default with Ubuntu.
When I follow the video manual on codename one web site: https://www.codenameone.com/download.html
I do not get option to install codename one plugin.
To be precise, there is not a single available plugin listed.
In Windows 7 this works fine however.

I don't even know, who should I attribute this problem to:

- Ubuntu 16.04 ? - which sucks and behaves weird compared to earlier Ubuntu versions (now for instance does not close the open and frozen NetBeans - had to kill -9 it)
- Net Beans 8.1 ? which runs just fine with Win7
- codename one ? Which I rather doubt :)
- or even me ? :)

Please give me any hints, if anyone ran into similar troubles, how do I fix it ?

Comment: Did you *"Note: The plugins.netbeans.org server has been down frequently ... follow the instructions [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/netbeans-plugin-update-center.html) as a workaround"*?

Comment: @zapl: Yeah, but in Win7 it works allways, in Ubuntu 16.04 never.
Could I be just "lucky" ?

Comment: I see the plugin just fine, 14.04 & fresh NetBeans 8.1. Do you have errors in netbeans log (`~/.netbeans/8.1/var/log/messages.log`)? A proxy that needs to be configured? Sth else that prevents free network access for netbeans?

Comment: Never mind, this is probably a wrong JDK. I use OpenJDK - and virtually all IDEs complain about problems with it.
Same on other PC with UBUNTU 14.04 - NetBeans refuses to install due to OpenJDK.
I'll just go with Pure Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

We need to the official Java 8 JDK for install since we need access to Java FX for things such as web browser/media support. If OpenJDK will ever work with Java FX properly then it should work fine with Codename One.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Part of the story is, that you should use original JDK from Oracle, not the pre-installed OpenJDK. Similarly, Android Studio will complain about incompatible JDK.

But secondly !  Using the NetBeans installation provided by Ubuntu SW center results in incomplete, or not updatable version. Simply you get no available plugins listed. Only those pre-installed. Moreover, this IDE freezes much too often. What the heck !?

Instead download and install NetBeans from [their site](https://netbeans.org/downloads/): 
I went for the full version.

For this and many other reasons I think I am done with Ubuntu 16.04
Every day it convinces me it does not YET deserve to occupy my disk space. I will probably step back to 14.04 LTS, until 16.04 LTS it reaches some mature state.